# Split string by a string token instead of a char token in Python

Tags: python, string, split

I've a string like:

`10-24-2017 10:09:18.218 - my_test - INFO - My Automation version 0.0.1`

And I wish to split the string by the token `" - "` (Note the leading and lagging white-spaces). IOW, the above string should be split as:

`{'10-24-2017 10:09:18.218', 'my_test', 'INFO', 'My Automation version 0.0.1'}`

If I just split by '-', then the date string will also be split which I don't wish to do. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: ... Did you try splitting by " - " yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.split` instead:

```
In [3]: re.split(' - ', '123-456 - foo - bar')
Out[3]: ['123-456', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Or just split by the whole string:

```
In [5]: '123-456 - foo - bar'.split(' - ')
Out[5]: ['123-456', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'10-24-2017 10:09:18.218 - my_test - INFO - My Automation version 0.0.1'.split(' - ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "10-24-2017 10:09:18.218 - my_test - INFO - My Automation version 0.0.1"
final_string = re.split("\s-\s", s)
```

Output:

```
['10-24-2017 10:09:18.218', 'my_test', 'INFO', 'My Automation version 0.0.1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use normal split function.

```
test_str = "10-24-2017 10:09:18.218 - my_test - INFO - My Automation version 0.0.1"

print(test_str.split(' - '))
```

Output:

```
['10-24-2017 10:09:18.218', 'my_test', 'INFO', 'My Automation version 0.0.1']
```